# PHP Function proceeded even after Return

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework,

In my Model, i have a function like this (simplified):

```
public function do_stuff($id=FALSE)
{
    // Get all rows from `Table A`
    $result_table_a = $this->db->get('table_a')->result_array();

    // Update `Table B` data
    $update_table_b = $this->db->update('table_b', $data);

    // If failed to update `Table B` return FALSE
    if ( !$update_table_b || $this->db->affected_rows()<1 )
    {
        $this->data['message'] = '<p>Failed to Update (#34)!</p>';
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Update all selected rows from `Table A`
    foreach ($result_table_a AS $result)
    {
        $this->function_to_update_table_a($some_data);
    }
}
```

Today i was running this function as a user, i saw the error `Failed to Update (#34)!` but then i noticed the `foreach` loop has also run and the function inside it has updated table_a as well

Is this possible? can a function continue to work after return?

I am really confused

Comment: That means you never reached your return statement. You need to figure out why.

Comment: Try debugging your code..

Comment: @JohnConde But then how is the error shown?

Comment: Maybe the method ran twice? *shrug*

Comment: @JonStirling Silly me, i must have clicked Submit twice, i will look into a way to prevent users from submitting the same form twice , thank you very much, just had to make sure

Comment: To answer we have to got view of whole situation. Sample scenario - if you fast clicked the button initiating the call of function - one time fails another time proceeds. ( It is a sample - I don't know how it is made on by you )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking to see if any rows were affected is not the correct way to determine if an update was successful. This is because if you try it to update it with the same values it will says no rows were updated.

I will assume that `$this->db->update()` returns a boolean, as such if you just change your if statement from `if ( !$update_table_b || $this->db->affected_rows()<1 )` to this `if ( !$update_table_b )` this should solve your problem.

Comment: Augwa, now i learned a lot, so worth asking even tho it was not good question, thank you